# Institution As A Retirement Account Beneficiary

Tags: united-states, retirement

If possible, what information do I need to have in order to have an institution (private K-12 school) be the beneficiary of my retirement accounts?

Comment: Ask whoever's administering those accounts. Or set the beneficiary to be "estate of {you}" and in your will direct those moneys to the school.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to ask the charity and the custodian of the retirement account. Both will want to make sure it is done correctly. The charity will want to be able to not have the account go through the probate process. Probate can delay to transfer of money for months or longer. Items in the will could be contested.

Comment: Exactly - the designated beneficiary on a retirement account skips probate. That's key.